# Macro expanding to a file's contents?

Tags: tex-core, external-files, e-tex

How can I define a macro so that it expands to a file's contents?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `catchfile` can be used also in Plain TeX.

Comment: @egreg It needs e-TeX, so if we are talking Knuth's plain then that's not an option

Answer (score 7):

You can use `catchfile.sty` also in Plain TeX, provided you use `pdftex` that has e-TeX extensions. With Knuth TeX it's beyond hope, I'm afraid.

```
\input catchfile.sty

\CatchFileDef{\foo}{\jobname.tex}{}

\show\foo
```

Here's the output:

```
> \foo=macro:
->\input catchfile.sty \par \CatchFileDef {\foo }{\jobname .tex}{} \par \show \foo \par .
```

Of course this is just to make the example self-contained; using `\foo` would be quite dangerous.

In the trailing argument you can add settings, for instance to catcodes or to `\endlinechar`.

With `\CatchFileEdef` the contents of the file would be fully expanded.

An approximation without e-TeX extension can be obtained by reading the file line by line:

```
\catcode`@=11
\newread\catch@in

\def\catchfile#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
  #3%
  \toks@={}%
  \openin\catch@in=#2
  \catch@file
  \edef\temp{\the\toks@}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{\temp}%
}
\def\catch@file{%
  \ifeof\catch@in
  \else
    \read\catch@in to \temp
    \toks@=\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\temp}%
    \expandafter\catch@file
  \fi
}
\catcode`@=12

\catchfile{\foo}{test.tex}{}
\show\foo
```

The example file `test.tex` is

```
first line

\noindent x
y
x
```

and the output is

```
> \foo=macro:
->first line \par \noindent x y x \par .
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about how the token registers are being used.  Part of my problem may be that I don't know what `\toks@` is and can't find it documentation (at least in TeX by Topic, I don't have a copy of the TeXbook with me this week).  Nevertheless, I see how the content of the file is getting assigned to `\toks0` but not how this is changes `\toks@`.  Care to elaborate?

Comment: @A.Ellett `\toks@` is an alias for `\toks0`; handier, because it's just one token. There was a typo, of course: I fixed it. Line 217 in `plain.tex` says `\toksdef\toks@=0`

Answer (score 4):

The eTeX register `\everyeof` can be used:

```
\everyeof = {EndOfFile!}
\long\def\scanfile#1EndOfFile!{\def\filecontent{#1}}
\expandafter\scanfile \input file
\everyeof = {}
```

If the file contents can be expanded during reading then there is more simple solution:

```
{\everyeof={\noexpand}\xdef\filecontent{\input file }}
```

Comment: This is basically what `catchfile.sty` does, but with a safer termination text, built with tokens having uncommon category codes.

Comment: Of course, that this is the core of the task. My solution shows this core in order user needn't to search this in 309 less transparent lines of `catchfile.sty`.